# #define inside an enum or how to extend an enum

Tags: c++, enums, macros, c-preprocessor

I have several classes each of them uses the same `enum` but extends it a bit, based on its requirements.
For example :

```
class skirtColor{
  enum Color{
red = 1,
blue = 10,
green = 12
};
};
class dressColor {
enum Color{
red = 1,
pink,
yellow,
blue = 10,
green = 12
};
};
class pantsColor {
enum Color {
red = 1,
brown,
blue = 10,
green = 12
};
};
```

Since there is no inheritance for enum in C++, I would like to use `define` for a  common part

```
#define COLOR\
// red color \
red = 1,\
// blue color \
blue = 10,\
//green color
green = 12,
```

After that I can reuse common color definition in classes

```
class skirtColor{
  enum Color{
COLOR
};
};
class dressColor {
enum Color{
COLOR
pink = 2,
yellow,
};
};
Class pantsColor {
enum Color {
COLOR
brown = 2,
};
};
```

Is this way OK?
I can't compile this code can you help me with correct macro definition?

Answer (score 5):

One way you can manage this kind of thing at present is inheritence which will inherit the constants from the class.

```
struct Color
{
     enum { red = 1, blue = 10, green = 12 };
} ;

struct DressColor : Color
{
     enum { pink =2, yellow = 3 };
};
```

and DressColor will also have red, blue and green..

If you want to enable "strict typing" to have a variable that must have one of these values you can do this with a class that "has-a" value and can only be constructed or modified from within the class.

```
struct Color
{
    class Holder
    {
        private:
        int value;
        explicit Holder( int v ) : value( v ) {}

        public:
        bool operator==( const Holder & other ) const
        {
            return value == other.value;
        }

        int get() const
        {
            return value;
        }

        friend struct Color;
    };

  protected:        
    static Holder makeHolder( int v )
    {
        return Holder( v );
    }

  public:
    static const Holder red;
    static const Holder blue;
    static const Holder green;
};


struct DressColor : Color
{
    static const Holder pink;
    static const Holder yellow;
};

     // these in a .cpp file.
const Color::Holder Color::red( 1 );
const Color::Holder Color::blue( 10 );
const Color::Holder Color::green( 12 );
const Color::Holder DressColor::pink( Color::makeHolder(2) );
const Color::Holder DressColor::yellow( Color::makeHolder(3) );

     // how you can create a variable of one. Note that whilst you cannot construct
     // a Color::Holder from an int in the regular way, you can copy-construct.

     Color::Holder var( Color::red );
```

Of course in this "workaround", the enum objects are still of type `Color::Holder` and cannot be of type `DressColor::Holder` for using `class DressColor`.

Comment: Cool, but the problem is that the enums themselves are nameless, so you have to use `int` for variables of any color.

Comment: I have just posted a solution that lets you work around that.

Comment: Eventually I need to write a function which returs the color for each of the classes.Can I do it with unnamed enum approach?

Comment: This now has a ring to java enums, not that it is bad _per se_, but I think it is getting to complex to be used in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/Q2mIRk

`Color` is not the same as `COLOR` here:

```
Enum Color{
Color
Pink = 2,
yellow,
};
```

Also, it's `enum` and `class`, all lower-case.

Also, ditch the comments:

```
#define COLOR\
// red color \
red = 1,\
// blue color \
blue = 10,\
//green color
green = 12,
```

because the trailing `\` will make everything into a comment. The above will expand to:

```
// red color red = 1, // blue color blue = 10, //green color green = 12,
```

Just say

```
#define COLOR \ 
red = 1,\
blue = 10,\
green = 12,
```

if there's someone that can't figure out what color `red` stands for... well, I'll just keep my mouth shut.

Comment: The uppercase thing happens when you write C using MS-Word (ugh!).

Answer (score 0):

**Your code does not even get the C++ keywords correct.**

And instances of your …`Color` classes do not represent colors, so the class names are somewhat misleading.

But anyway…

---

Extending an `enum` is non-trivial in that it requires superclassing, not subclassing, which is why it isn't supported by the language.

But it seems you're only interested in having the *names* available, not any strong typing, in which case you can do …

```
struct SkirtColors
{
    enum { red = 1, blue = 10, green = 12 };
};

struct DressColors
    : SkirtColors
{
    enum { pink = 2, yellow = 3 };
};
```

Comment: ok someone else has answered about the same but without the information about why it's a bad idea type-wise. i was delayed by Avira anti-virus, which identified [foo.exe] (from running the above code through visual c++ compiler) as malware. shitty AV, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to start with an `enum` that names **all** of the colors, then add enums for the various specific ones and use the values from the first:

```
struct colors {
    enum colors {
        red = 1,
        blue = 10,
        pink = 2,
        green = 12,
        yellow = 3
    }; 
};

struct skirt_colors {
    enum colors {
        red = colors::red,
        blue = colors::blue,
        green = colors::green
    };
};
```